# Error calling python script for database from cmd

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, sqlite

I am a programming student and we are working on SQL injecion attacks - the trouble is I cant get the database to run on my computer. The task is to simulate an API call to a SQL database and uses a python script - I have installed python 2.7 and sqlite 3, and the python script is run from cmd using

```
python count_stock.py '{"productId":1}'
```

(script is below) and I have added both python and SQLite3 to PATH. I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_stock.py", line 12, in <module>
    input_json = json.loads(arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Have I done something daft!!??

Python Script:

```
import sys, sqlite3, json

company_db_file = 'company_data.db'

# Connect to the DB
conn = sqlite3.connect(company_db_file)
c = conn.cursor()

# Count and print stock numbers for product id
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:

    input_json = json.loads(arg)
    c.execute("SELECT amount FROM product WHERE id = " + str(input_json['productId']))
    sys.stdout.write(str(c.fetchall())+ "\n")

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Yes; using Windows is daft. ;-) Quoting in `cmd` works differently; try `"{\"productId\":1}"` or `"{""productId"":1}"`.

Comment: thanks, actually put it in another script and called from there so no need for double quotes